# Electric Steam Cooker

Tags: steaming

I'm planning to purchase an Electric steam cooker, however, I'm concerned that the plastic surface which comes in contact with the food will eventually leach into the food.

Is it just better to use steel & bamboo ones? or should I buy electric & consider naturally lining it with lettuce or maybe lining it with parchment paper?

What do you guys do?

Comment: Before I answer, please clarify the following --- what will you be cooking in it? Are you planning on buying a cheap Wal-mart one or a more expensive one? What is the frequency of use you expect?

Comment: I'll cook mostly soft vegetables like spinach, broccoli, carrots, asparagus, colliflowers, etc I don't mind buying a pricy one if it serves me better but I was thinking to go with hamilton beach? the frequency is almost twice a week.